# Gstreamer - streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated

Tags: networking, video-streaming, gstreamer

I am trying to stream video over local network using gstreamer between jetson tx1 and my pc.
I made sure that my camera has no problem and my devices are connected via local network.

Here is my terminal commands: 
First of all, I use `ssh` command to connect to my nvidia jetson tx1 which has the camera connected.
Then, on jetson I run this:

```
sudo gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! videorate max-rate=25 ! videoconvert ! omxh265enc qp-range=30,50:30,50:30,50 control-rate=4 bitrate=3000000 ! "video/x-h265, stream-format=(string)byte-stream" ! rtph265pay mtu=1400 ! udpsink host=192.168.1.5 port=5700 sync=false async=false
```

This is the output:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
Framerate set to : 25 at NvxVideoEncoderSetParameterNvMMLiteOpen : Block : BlockType = 8 
===== MSENC =====
NvMMLiteBlockCreate : Block : BlockType = 8 
===== NVENC blits (mode: 1) into block linear surfaces =====
```

Then I left this window of terminal hanging.

After that on my pc I run this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5700 ! application/x-rtp, encoding-name=H265, payload=96 ! rtph265depay ! h265parse ! queue ! avdec_h265 ! fpsdisplaysink sync=false
```

And this is the output:

```
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
Redistribute latency...
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0: Internal data flow error.
Additional debug info:
gstbasesrc.c(2947): gst_base_src_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstUDPSrc:udpsrc0:
streaming task paused, reason not-negotiated (-4)
Execution ended after 0:00:00.382685021
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Setting pipeline to READY ...
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
Freeing pipeline ...
```

So I cannot preview the stream. 
What can I do about that?
Thank you.